# How can I read file properties/metadata?

Tags: c#

I wanted read system file properties like the same shown in the picture below, specifically the *Title* and *Copyright* properties. How can I do this?

[image: **Read yellow details **]

Answer (score 2):

Generally you can use `System.Diagnostics`,

```
FileVersionInfo info = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("path\to\file");
```

Then examine the `FileDescription` and `LegalCopyright` properties. However for images the case is different, you need to extract the bitmap metadata explicitly. Consider,

```
using (Stream fs = File.Open("path\to\file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
    BitmapDecoder decoder = 
        BitmapDecoder.Create(
            fs, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
    BitmapFrame frame = decoder.Frames[0]; // the first frame with the metadata
    BitmapMetadata metadata = frame.Metadata as BitmapMetadata;
    if (metadata != null)
    {
        // examine metadata.Title, metadata.Copyright
    }
    fs.Close();
}
```

You can find all the properties listed at the [BitmapMetadata Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapmetadata%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation on MSDN.

Comment: It showing nothing tried with both properties none of them returned value but empty string.

Comment: Thanks for help but still not able to fix the issue. The editor is showing error "The type or namespace  BitmapDecoder is not found " tried with namespace  using System.Windows.Media.Imaging; but the editor is not able to locate "Media".

Comment: @SuryaKantTripathi The namespace is correct. Have you added the PresentationCore.dll assembly to your project? And are you using a recent .net?

Comment: Yes, I have added "PresentationCore.dll" in my solution but still it shows same error. I am using VS2013 Ultimate.

Comment: @SuryaKantTripathi This makes little sense - if you added the PresentationCore assembly to your references and added a `using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;` to the top of your class, but still don't have `BitmapDecoder` recognised - you have a *separate* setup issue that has little to do with this question and the answer.

Comment: Working for `jpg` but not for `png` what could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to load the image into a Bitmap, and access the **PropertyItems**.

```
  Bitmap image = new Bitmap("YOUR IMAGE PATH HERE");
    PropertyItem[] propItems = image.PropertyItems;
```

The following would get the manufacturer...

```
System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
string manufacturer = encoding.GetString(propItems[1].Value);
```

You need to do similar conversions depending on what details you are after.

```
    foreach (PropertyItem item in propItems)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("ID : " + item.Id + " , VALUE : " +  encoding.GetString(item.Value));

    }
```

Comment: It's not helping. I wanted to read an Image property like Copyright of the image and Title.

Comment: @ Stephen Borg It is showing ID in numeric and value as System.byte[]